# Run Websockets server in django

Tags: python, django, websocket

I want to run [Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) python-based library on Django.

for example:

```
# WS server example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This sample run websockets server, but it blocks Django from running (because of the `event_loop().run_forever()` part).

**Note:** I'm a beginner at Django

Answer (score 0):

I use [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for websockets in Django. It is nicely supported with Django. Have a look into it and let me know if you need any help in using it.